# How to run method in a task in for loop and only create a thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task

```
for(i=0,i<1000,i++){ 
   //method1 or
   Task.Run(()=> MyTask()) 
   //method2 
   Task.Factory.StartNew(MyTask) 
} // sample code
```

I want MyTask to Run 1000 times，but i don't want to create 1000 threads.

I only want one thread, how can i achieve this by changing the sample code ?

Comment: If you only want to create one thread, why not just move the task creation to *outside* the loop? i.e. start a single task which runs all the iterations.

Comment: May be you're looking for `Parallel.For`?

Answer (score 3):

Move the loop into `MyTask` or wrap it in another method that does the looping:

```
Task.Run(() => My1000Tasks());

private void My1000Tasks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
        MyTask();
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I had copied the `for` statement from the OP, which doesn't compile. It's fixed now